# Word forward/backward delimiter difference between bash and zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, zsh-completion

Having been dragged into the 21st century by macOS Catalina now defaulting to `zsh` instead of `bash` for its shell, I'm trying to restore some of the bash's line editing behavior. Specifically, if I am at the end of the line:

```sh
bash$ ls /foo/bar/baz
```

and I hit Alt-Left Arrow, the cursor jumps to "baz", then "bar", then "foo". It is treating the slash as a word delimiter, as do most environments (such as Safari and apps that use Cocoa text editing features).

In `zsh`, when I try to do the same thing, the first Alt-Left Arrow jumps the cursor all the way back to the beginning of "/foo/bar/baz", which makes it much less useful for editing parts of a long directly.

Can this be configured in zsh? If so, how?

Comment: You can install and use a modern version of `bash` if you like.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48577/modifying-the-zsh-shell-word-split I think

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Characters in zsh variable WORDCHARS are considered part of a word.

You just need to remove / from it

```
% echo "$WORDCHARS"
*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>
% WORDCHARS="${WORDCHARS/\//}"
# Now Alt-left-arrow will stop at /
```

Just be aware that $WORDCHARS is used in other situations as well. See `man zshall`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I wonder why slash isn't included in the default, since much of line-editing involves fiddling with long file paths…

Comment: How to make `|` from being considered a word char?

Comment: @HappyFace By default `|` is not part of a word. Can you run `echo "$WORDCHARS"` to see if it contains `|` ?

Comment: @Philippe I just noticed that I needed to add `|` to `WORDCHARS` to get my desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48589/375296

Comment: thank you so so so much :) I wish I had found out this 5 years ago. All I figured  was enabling meta in terminal preferences but that wouldn't help me with editing long paths.